# Compiling some classes during unit tests only

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a reusable custom class to help mocking localStorage during unit tests (inspired by [this blog post](https://medium.com/@armno/til-mocking-localstorage-and-sessionstorage-in-angular-unit-tests-a765abdc9d87)) :

```
export class MockLocalStorage {

  static mock(store = {}) {
    const mockLocalStorage = {
      getItem: (key: string): string => {
        return key in store ? store[key] : null;
      },
      setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
        store[key] = `${value}`;
      },
      removeItem: (key: string) => {
        delete store[key];
      },
      clear: () => {
        store = {};
      },
    };

    spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.getItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem').and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.setItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'removeItem').and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.removeItem);
    spyOn(localStorage, 'clear').and.callFake(mockLocalStorage.clear);
  }
}
```

The problem is that it uses some calls to `spyOn` which is only defined during unit tests. This causes some compilation errors during the build.

I can rewrite this without using spyOn for this specific case but as I will need to make other reusable classes for unit tests, I would really like to have a generic way to exclude test utility classes during the normal build.

Should I name the file with `.spec.ts` even if it does not contain any test ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to appease the compiler by simply declaring the `spyOn` function as a global variable:

```
declare var spyOn: Function;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that placing test utility files in a `test` folder **at the root of the project** solves the problem.